# python как корретно сравнить значения листа со ключами словаря

Tags: python, list, циклы, словари, re

```
list_symbols = ["EURUSDrfd", "GBPUSDrfd", "AUDUSDrfd","USDCADrfd"]   
dict_symbols = {"eurusd": 
                   {"price": 1.05},
                "gbpusd": 
                   {"price": 1.22},
                "audusd":
                   {"price": 1.09} }
     

for symbol in list_symbols:
    if symbol in list(dict_symbols.keys()):   # как осушествить проверку в цикле на подобие ??
        print(f"{symbol} find !")
    else:
        print(f"{symbol} not find !")
```

- Значения списка не совпадают полностью со значениями ключей словаря, т.е частично равны.

Пример: "EURUSDrfd" = "eurusd"

Заметка: данные в списке могут меняться в след раз: было "**EURUSDrfd", стало "rfdEURUSD"**

Comment: Используйте списки синонимов, например. Зависит от границ возможного колебания. Можете их определить? Например, вряд ли вы "USDRUBTOD" захотите сопоставить с "USDRUBTOМ". А разница - в одну букву.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а если зайти с другой стороны, например вот так:

```
from re import search

list_symbols = ["EURUSDrfd", "GBPUSDrfd", "AUDUSDrfd", "USDCADrfd", "rfdEURUSD"]   
dict_symbols = {"eurusd": {"price": 1.05},
                "gbpusd": {"price": 1.22},
                "audusd": {"price": 1.09}}

for symbol in list_symbols:
    if search(fr'{"|".join(dict_symbols)}',symbol.lower()):
        print(f'{symbol} found')

'''
EURUSDrfd found
GBPUSDrfd found
AUDUSDrfd found
rfdEURUSD found
```

Comment: Отличный вариант и однострочник при этом )) ... Спасиб ВаМ :)

Answer (score 3):

Если лишние символы всегда одинаковые, то можно их просто убирать через `replace`, ну и ещё приводить в нужный регистр потом:

```
for symbol in list_symbols:
    symbol = symbol.replace('rfd', '').lower()
    ...
```

Вывод:

```
eurusd find !
gbpusd find !
audusd find !
usdcad not find !
```

В более сложных случаях возможно пригодится библиотека [нечёткого сравнения](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz)

Comment: Судя по специфике области и задачи маловероятно, что там символы лишние всегда будут одинаковыми. А библиотека в ссылке подойдет для моего примера из комментариев? Если она на расстоянии Левенштейна базируется, то она отличит "USDRUBTOD" от "USDRUBTOМ", например?

Comment: @Сергей Если начать глубоко копать, то `USDRUBTOD` и `USDRUBTOM` - это два разных финансовых инструмента, хотя и очень похожих. И хорошо бы тогда автору вопроса разобраться в матчасти прежде чем пытаться сопоставлять финансовые инструменты просто по похожести названий без вникания в их суть :)  Я исходил из того, что всё же у него там однотипные какие-то названия инструментов, но всё может быть. По большому счёту сопоставлять надо не по названиям, а по `id` или по какому-то стандартному наименованию.

Comment: CrazyElf, я том же. Я просто знаю эту область немного и представляю, что там может оказаться, если работают в стиле: "было "EURUSDrfd", стало "rfdEURUSD". Если нет конкретных правил на допустимые отклонения, то очень сложно будет.

Comment: @Сергей У меня вообще прошлая работа была в брокере )  Узнал много нового про финансовые инструменты. Там чёрт ногу сломит так то вообще ))